# Unable to resolve service for type 'IBatchProducts' while attempting to activate 'ProductBatcherController'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

UPDATE: I created a github repository with a load of stuff taken out(not sure if fully minimal) which still produces the same error message: https://github.com/georalroscoe/DebuggingServiceIssue.git

This is the error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Application.Interfaces.IBatchProducts' while attempting to activate 'PrivateWebAPI.Controllers.ProductBatcherController'.

```
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
```

**Repository**

```cs
public interface IBatchProducts
{
}

public class ProductBatcher : IBatchProducts
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<WarehouseBatchContent> _warehouseBatchContentRepo;

    public ProductBatcher(
        IGenericRepository<WarehouseBatchContent> warehouseBatchContentRepo,
        IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _warehouseBatchContentRepo = warehouseBatchContentRepo;
        _uow = uow;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```cs
public class ProductBatcherController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBatchProducts _productBatcher;
    public ProductBatcherController(IBatchProducts productBatcher)
    {
        _productBatcher = productBatcher;
    }

    // POST api/<ProductBatcherController>
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] ProductBatcherDto dto)
    {
        _productBatcher.BatchMover(dto);
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<DepotContext>(options => options
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddScoped<DbContext, DepotContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

   
    services.AddTransient<IBatchProducts, ProductBatcher>();
    services.AddTransient<IGenericRepository<WarehouseBatchContent>, GenericRepository<WarehouseBatchContent>>();
    services.AddTransient<IGenericRepository<WarehouseBatch>, GenericRepository<WarehouseBatch>>();

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen();
}
```

I've looked over it countless times and can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

I expected this to send a post request using swagger to api/.ü

Comment: From the code posted, your IBatchProducts appears to have been registered correctly.  Is there an inner exception?  The error could be caused by a deeper dependency, e.g. in the constructor of your UnitOfWork or the GenericRepository.  Also, your AddControllers() method is redundant if you've already used AddMvc().  See ... https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/difference-between-addmvc-and-addmvccore-method/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've no reason to believe there are errors with my UOW or GR constructors.  public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

Comment: GR constructor:  public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

            if (_context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

            _dbSet = _context.Set<T>();
        }

Comment: However I'm still a beginner coder so could be missing something. Is there a way I can debug to find an inner exception if there is one?

Comment: Your showing codes are all good，I tried them with no errors. Maybe you can disable some function until it works. Then add them back 1 by 1 to see which part is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried switching around the repositories since your generic repository gets loaded last. I don't think this should be the issue but it is worth a try plus it is more logical to implement the generic repositories first

Comment: Just switched them round then with no luck but still good to know, thanks! I'll give that a shot now @QiangFu :)

Comment: Just to have asked: Have you tried cleaning/rebuilding your solution or restarting your IDE?

Comment: I've tried restarting my IDE and have tried so many combinations in my solution that I may as well have rebuilt it!

Comment: The most likely cause of this error is that the `IBatchProducts` that `ProductBatcherController` depends on, is a different type than the `IBatchProducts` that `ConfigureServices` registers. You likely created a second `IBatchProducts` type accidentally. MS.DI, unfortunately, isn't very good in telling you this is the case.

Comment: And otherwise, start with a clean, empty project/solution and create a minimal, reproducible example by adding the minimum amount of code that reproduces the problem. Often you'll find your mistake by using this process. If not, update your question with that minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks Steven. When I hover over IBatchProducts in both of those files it comes up with the same result so I don't think it's that. That sounds like a good idea to find my issue, I'll get on it now

Comment: I've updated it with a git repository which is as minimal as I could make it without a bunch of errors because of dependencies @Steven. https://github.com/georalroscoe/DebuggingServiceIssue.git

Comment: The most interesting thing I found is no matter what injection I put in my controller I get the same error message

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was using a startup file when it wasn't needed, the configuration should have been in my program file